# Engine type tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [two-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-stroke), [four-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-stroke), and [rotary-engine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotary-engine). I'm wondering if it would make sense to have a standard form of engine nomenclature, perhaps just 'type' rather than 'type-engine' (e.g., 'radial' vs. 'radial-engine')?

Comment: Although radial could be confusing, as that could also apply to tires as well.

Comment: Clarity of meaning is more important than consistency